# Json Object conversion to java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following json data

```
{"id":10606,
 "name":"ProgrammerTitle",
 "objectMap":{"programme-title":"TestProgramme","working-title":"TestProgramme"}
}
```

I want to set this data to my pojo object

```
public class TestObject {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("programme-title")
    private String programmeTitle;

    @JsonProperty("working-title")
    private String workingTitle;
}
```

Here i am able to set id and name in my test object but for object map i am not able to set data.

So i have made on more class for ObjectMap which contains programmeTitle & workingTitle this works fine but i can't set this fields directly to my pojo object 
is this possible to set?

I am using Jackson Object Mapper to convert json data.

It is working fine if i create another java object inside my pojo like:

```
public class TestObject {
private Long id;
private String name;

@JsonProperty("objectMap")
private ObjectMap objectMap;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ObjectMap getObjectMap() {
    return objectMap;
}

public void setObjectMap(ObjectMap objectMap) {
    this.objectMap = objectMap;
}
```

}

```
public class ObjectMap {

@JsonProperty("programme-title")
private String programmeTitle;

@JsonProperty("working-title")
private String workingTitle;

public String getProgrammeTitle() {
    return programmeTitle;
}

public void setProgrammeTitle(String programmeTitle) {
    this.programmeTitle = programmeTitle;
}

public String getWorkingTitle() {
    return workingTitle;
}

public void setWorkingTitle(String workingTitle) {
    this.workingTitle = workingTitle;
}
```

}

Comment: check out this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Your json object and Java POJO does not match. `TestObject->programme-title` is not same as `Obj->objectMap->programme-title`

Comment: Hi i have checked the post given i get it but i want to use json object which is inside that object is this possible ?

Comment: It is not possibel to define this kind of mapping using annotations. But you can implement your custom deserializer for this type and use it in deserialization process. See this link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/custom-deserializer-in-jackson-and-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON is like this

```
{"id":10606,
  "name":"ProgrammerTitle",
  "objectMap":{"programme-title":"TestProgramme","working-title":"TestProgramme"}
}
```

then you may write your object mapper class like this..

```
public class Program{

    public static class ObjectMap{
     private String programme_title, working_title;

      public String getprogramme_title() { return programme_title; }
     public String getworking_title() { return working_title; }

     public void setprogramme_title(String s) { programme_title= s; }
     public void setworking_title(String s) { working_title= s; }
   }

   private ObjectMap objMap;

   private String name;

   public ObjectMap getobjectMap () { return objMap; }
   public void setObjectMap  (ObjectMap n) { objMap= n; }

   private Long id;
   public Long getId() {return id;}
   public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

   private String name;
   public String getName() {return name;}
   public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
  }
```

please refer this [check it](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Comment: hi i want to set programmeTitle directly which is inside TestObject.I don't want to use another ObjectMap inside TestObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own deserializer for this class:

```
class EntityJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Entity> {

    @Override
    public Entity deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Root root = jp.readValueAs(Root.class);

        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.setId(root.id);
        entity.setName(root.name);
        if (root.objectMap != null) {
            entity.setProgrammeTitle(root.objectMap.programmeTitle);
            entity.setWorkingTitle(root.objectMap.workingTitle);
        }

        return entity;
    }

    private static class Root {
        public Long id;
        public String name;
        public Title objectMap;
    }

    private static class Title {
        @JsonProperty("programme-title")
        public String programmeTitle;

        @JsonProperty("working-title")
        public String workingTitle;
    }
}
```

Your entity:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EntityJsonDeserializer.class)
class Entity {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String programmeTitle;
    private String workingTitle;

    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

And usage example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Entity entity = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Entity.class);
        System.out.println(entity);
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
Entity [id=10606, name=ProgrammerTitle, programmeTitle=TestProgramme, workingTitle=TestProgramme]
```