# Parse JSON to Java Object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I'm here asking for your help after one week of headache :S

I need to deserialize this JSON Output using Jackson

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "142065955831788",
         "name": "Name1",
         "link": "http://www.somelink.com",
      },
      {
         "id": "160212467350470",
         "name": "Name2",
         "link": "http://www.somelink2.com",
      }
      .
      .
      .
}
```

I swear i've tried anything but I just can't make jackson deserialize that JSON.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I've created a class like this:

Data.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Data{

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private String link;

//Getters + Setters
```

And this is my code for the mapping

```
ObjectMapper mObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ArrayList<Data> mDataList;

        mDataList = mObjectMapper.readValue(
                url, /* The url returning the JSON */
                mObjectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
                        ArrayList.class, Data.class
                )
        );
```

And i get this error message:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Can you pls share your effort ?

Comment: "What am I missing?" : the error message maybe ?

Comment: this may help you to understand how to deserialize http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109719/json-object-conversion-to-java-object-using-jackson

Comment: Updated the OP. Sorry for before

Comment: Does it work if your remove the block `"data": [` in your json ?

Comment: @mreiterer I've tried by removing @JsonProperty("data") but it keeps giving me the same error. EDIT: I've read better your comment, I can't modify the JSON Response :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class data {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id ;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name ;

    @JsonProperty("link")
    private String link;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

}

public class aa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {

            data[] d = mapper.readValue(
                            "[{\"id\":\"142065955831788\",\"name\":\"Name1\",\"link\":\"http://www.somelink.com\"},{\"id\":\"160212467350470\",\"name\":\"Name2\",\"link\":\"http://www.somelink2.com\"}]",
                            data[].class);

            for (data data1 : d) {
                System.out.println("-----");
                System.out.println("Id : "+data1.getId());
                System.out.println("Name : "+data1.getName());
                System.out.println("Link : "+data1.getLink());
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Your JSON also need to be changed. It should not contain data part as you are using array of its properties.

Output -

```
-----
Id : 142065955831788
Name : Name1
Link : http://www.somelink.com
-----
Id : 160212467350470
Name : Name2
Link : http://www.somelink2.com
```

Comment: That code works if I dont have te data [] part in my JSON, but I can't modify the JSON response :(

Comment: You have array of data right..in your question there is [ in JSON...Also if array is not there you can get single object using `data d = mapper.readValue(
                            "{\"id\":\"142065955831788\",\"name\":\"Name1\",\"link\":\"http://www.somelink.com\"}",
                            data.class);`